# Excel VBA. Search if Cell Containing Specific Text from multiple Sheets And ONLY Certain Parts of the found cell

Tags: excel, vba

Thanks for taking time to take a look at the problems i am facing..
Been searching and testing for quite a bit but still didnt manage to find out what went wrong.

Right now i have no idea what went wrong.

Below is the current code

[this is sheets to be searched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3p14w.png)

[Red area is where the model number is enter, and price is from search results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ul0nC.png)

```html
Sub Search()
    Dim LR As Long, i2 As Long
    totalsheets = Worksheets.Count
    
    For i = 1 To totalsheets
        If Worksheets(i).Name <> "Main" Then
        lastrow = Worksheets(i).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            For j = 2 To lastrow
                If UCase(Worksheets(i).Range("C" & j).Value) Like "*A1-1-35-01*" Then
                Worksheets("Main").Activate
                Worksheets("Main").Range(k, 4).Value = Worksheets("Main").Range("A", j)
            lastrow = Worksheets("Main").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                    

                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: `Worksheets("Main").Range(k, 4).Value = Worksheets("Main").Range("A", j)` - what is `k`, and those aren't valid range references. First step, add `Option Explicit` to the top of the module. Then fix the range references.

Comment: When posting code you're having a problem with, it's useful to explain exactly what the problem is, including any error messages and which line(s) produce the error.